# BMW radiator problems

Tags: bmw, radiator

My radiator is spewing water when it is shut down. No hoses are leaking. Comes out of the bottom of the BMW and there isn't any over heating that the gauge shows.Can I still drive it if I fill the reservoir until a repair?

Comment: You are not filling the expansion tank to the very top each time are you?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Which BMW is this? Model and year?

Comment: Are you sure its your radiator and not the AirConditioning condenser defrosting?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue with BMW engines - presumably your car is about 10 years or so old, as what occurs is that the plastics used for the coolant overflow tank and associated plastic parts decay and begin to leak. I know this as I have purchased a couple of BMW 3 series, they both had small coolant tank leaks and the problem is well known in various BMW forums.

The onset will be small seeps but the real danger here is that there will come a time when the overflow tank simply fails. If you are driving, you need to notice this and stop immediately. Otherwise you will overheat the engine and warp the cylinder head. At best, you will be stranded.

It sounds like your problem has progressed past a seep. Replace the coolant tank as soon as possible. Either by doing it yourself or using a BMW knowledgeable mechanic. They will no doubt have seen it many times before and will be familiar with the part replacement process.

Comment: Without knowing which BMW this is, it is difficult to generalize the root cause as you have done here.

Comment: I would have said the same - had I not owned BMWs in the past and seen this issue discussed over and over. It happens on both the E46 and E90 models which span 1998 to 2011.